# How to pass meteor template helper as a parameter to meteor event handler?

Tags: meteor

Here's my problem:

in template file:

```
<template name="button">
     <button class="btn-class">{{disp}}</button>
</template>
```

in js:

```
Template.button.events({
    'click': function(event, templ) {
         if (this.onClick) {
             this.onClick();
         }
    }
})
```

in other template which use the 'button':

```
<template name="buttonGroup">
     {{> button disp='button 1' onClick=onButton1Click}}
     {{> button disp='button 2' onClick=onButton2Click}}
</template>
```

and its js:

```
Template.buttonGroup.helpers({
    onButton1Click: function() {
        console.log('button 1 is clicked');
    },
    onButton2Click: function() {
        console.log('button 1 is clicked');
    },
});
```

Obviously, it can NOT work, because template buttonGroup will pass 'onButton1Click()' to button, not the function but result(which returns 'undefined').

So how can I do that will make meteor pass the helper function as parameter to sub template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return functions inside your helpers instead of directly putting the code you want to execute :

```
Template.buttonGroup.helpers({
  onButton1Click: function() {
    return function(event, template){
      console.log('button 1 is clicked');
    };
  },
  onButton2Click: function() {
    return function(event, template){
      console.log('button 1 is clicked');
    };
  }
});

Template.button.events({
  "click": function(event, template) {
    if (this.onClick) {
      this.onClick(event, template);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using a global dictionary of functions be an option?

JS:

```
var fns = {
    onButton1Click: function(self) {
         // use self instead of this here
        console.log('button 1 is clicked');
    },
    onButton2Click: function(self) {
        console.log('button 1 is clicked');
    }
}

Template.button.events({
    'click': function(event, templ) {
         if (this.onClick) {
             fns[this.onClick](this);
         }
    }
})
```

HTML remains unchanged.